# Why Array.prototype.sort has different behavior in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I was trying to sort an Array And i got this different behavior in *Chrome V79* than *Firefox Dev Edition V72* (both in Desktop version).

This was the test,

```
console.log([4, 2, 5, 1, 3].sort((a, b) => a>b));
console.log(Array.prototype.sort.call([4, 2, 5, 1, 3], (a, b) => a>b));
```

### In Firefox Dev, I get this result,

[image: Firefox Test Result]

### But In Chrome, Why I get this result,

[image: 1st Chrome Test Result]

#### But When I i Pass the same array with var, I get this,

[image: 2nd Chrome Test Result]

But Yeah it sorts the Array and REWRITES THE VARIABLE but returns the unsorted version of the Array. So, When I am passing The Array directly without any var, i get no sorting. But,

### As per [MDN's reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Return_value) shouldn't it return the sorted Array ??

### Why there's difference ??

> Note: In the Example Imgs, there are two exmaple's I was practicing `call` func. And forgot to remove it. So, just ignore it. Both of 'em are same.

Comment: As it says in the link you posted, you need to return a number. You are supposed to return `0`, `1`, or `-1` from the sort function, not a boolean.

Comment: you may read why a boolean return value is a bad idea ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785/sorting-in-javascript-shouldnt-returning-a-boolean-be-enough-for-a-comparison

Comment: Opps, Yeah i got the mistake. But how firefox is showing the properly sorted array ??

Comment: I think .sort((a,b) => a-b); is the cleanest way to sort array ascending.

Comment: @AnonymousUser264 the particulars of how `.sort()` should be implemented are not part of the spec. Chrome and Firefox have slightly different algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you guys

Comment: Boolean values can be coerced into numbers, but if they are, true = 1 and false = 0. The problem is that for a sorting callback, returning 0 means "these values are equal". Until very recently (as in, the standards introduced last year), there was no guarantee that the implementation of `Array.sort` was stable -- that is, there was no guarantee that equal values would retain their relative positions. Thus, returning false/0 when `a < b` might "happen" to work for stable sort and not for unstable sort or vice-versa, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the function you provide for sorting should return:

- A positive number if `a` is greater than `b`
- A negative number if `b` is greater than `a`
- 0 if they are equal

Therefore, a simple expression you could return is `a - b` instead of `a > b` (if you want to sort ascendingly):

```js
console.log([4, 2, 5, 1, 3].sort((a, b) => a-b));
```